# How can I set my entity field to "nullable=false"?

Tags: php, symfony, join, null, entity

I am connecting my entity "data" with my entity "documents"

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Documents")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="document", referencedColumnName="id")
   */

  private $document;
```

If the data is not connected to any document, then my database shows NULL.
But I want it to be empty, when it is not connected. This is my approach:

```
   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Documents")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="document", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
   */

  private $document;
```

But I get an error message:

> Migration 20190405143905 failed during Execution. Error An exception
>   occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE data CHANGE document document
>   INT NOT NULL':
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE data CHANGE
>   document document INT NOT NULL':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1832 Cannot change column
>   'document': used in a foreign key constraint 'FK_ADF3F363D8698A76'

Comment: What do you mean by __empty__?

Comment: @u_mulder I mean, in the database the field is NULL NULL NULL. I just want no content, just blank. Is this possible?

Comment: And what's the problem with NULL, it's a blank value too

Comment: @u_mulder Hm, ok. Then I did not really understand what is the purpose of NULL. It looked to me like an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the document(s) entries linked to your data, otherwise you are breaking the foreign key constraint. Then you can set the document ID to null inside the data occurrence

If you can't delete the documents entries because you need them, then I recommend you migrate them to a temporary table, do the required changes on your database model, and then put the documents entries back into the original table